# Data Model : Cassandra Table for Multiple Primary key

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, composite-primary-key

I need a data model for Cassandra table for below requirement.

Note: This is helpful for joining two kafka topic and any update is happening any one of the kafka, both will be reflected in denormalized format at Cassandra table

```
create table stackoverflow_composite (
      key_part_one text,
      key_part_two int,
      data text,
      PRIMARY KEY(key_part_one, key_part_two)      
  );
  
insert into stackoverflow_composite (key_part_one, key_part_two, data) 
  VALUES ('ronaldo', 9, 'football player');
insert into stackoverflow_composite (key_part_one, key_part_two, data) 
  VALUES ('ronaldo', 10, 'ex-football player');
insert into stackoverflow_composite (key_part_one, key_part_two, data) 
  VALUES ('ronaldo', 11, 'ex-football player');

select * from stackoverflow_composite where key_part_one = 'ronaldo';

 key_part_one | key_part_two | data
--------------+--------------+--------------------
      ronaldo |            9 |    football player
      ronaldo |           10 | ex-football player
```

As per our requirement , any one of the value of primary key is the same , should be upserted. not inserted .

```
insert into stackoverflow_composite (key_part_one, key_part_two, data) 
  VALUES ('Messi', 10, 'ex-football player');
```

Based on the Second primary key

```
cqlsh:key1> select * from stackoverflow_composite ;

 key_part_one | key_part_two | data
--------------+--------------+--------------------
      ronaldo |            9 |    football player
      Messi   |           10 | ex-football player
```

Based on the Second First Primary key

```
insert into stackoverflow_composite (key_part_one, key_part_two, data) 
  VALUES ('Messi', 12, 'ex-football player');

 cqlsh:key1> select * from stackoverflow_composite ;

 key_part_one | key_part_two | data
--------------+--------------+--------------------
      ronaldo |            9 |    football player
      Messi   |           12 | ex-football player
```

Comment: Edited with corrected example :

Comment: Can you specify what read queries are you going to execute against the data model? It is important in Cassandra to build your model based on the queries you are going to execute

Comment: Thanks for Your Response. Please find the more details.Consider --              
 Table-A is having the 3 columns . Col-1,Col-2,Col-3. Without considering the primary key all records in table should be get updated if any update from source.

col-1 | col-2 | col-3
----------------------------
100   | 11    | Blue
200   | 11    | Blue
300   | 11    | Green

All col-3 = 'Blue' Should be updated with 'Red' without considering Key value

Comment: I understand this point already, my question was about your read queries (select queries)....what are you going to ask Cassandra about?

Comment: Select query will be based on the primary key .. that won't be an issue.

Comment: Which part of the primary key would you search with?
according to you examples you have queries like:
`select * from stackoverflow_composite where key_part_one = 'ronaldo';`
here you are restricting only `key_part_one` which is the partition key part, so my question is are you going to have queries that restricts the `key_part_two` also?
For example:
`select * from stackoverflow_composite where key_part_two = 10;`

Comment: No , we are going to restrict on only with one primary key .key_part_one

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one bit complicated solution (as your requirement is also complicated).

First you need to make the primary key be only one column `key_part_one`.

`create table stackoverflow_composite (
      key_part_one text,
      key_part_two int,
      data text,
      PRIMARY KEY(key_part_one)
  );`

Before you insert, execute a query that tries to find the `key_part_two` first, to be able to query this column directly without restricting the `partition key` (key_part_one) you must create a [secondary index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSecondaryIndex.html) on this column:

`CREATE INDEX key_part_two_index ON stackoverflow_composite (key_part_two);`

Then do a query like this before you insert:

`select * from stackoverflow_composite where key_part_two = 10;`

If you find any rows returned then, you should execute an update not an insert, for example if you want to insert a row:

`insert into stackoverflow_composite (key_part_one, key_part_two, data) 
  VALUES ('Messi', 10, 'ex-football player');`

Instead you should update the rest of columns other than key_part_two:

`update stackoverflow_composite set key_part_one='Messi', data='ex-football player' where key_part_two=10;`

Else if no rows where found for that value of key_part_two then you should execute you normal insert:

`insert into stackoverflow_composite (key_part_one, key_part_two, data) 
  VALUES ('Messi', 10, 'ex-football player');`

Note that even if that value of key_part_one already existed before all the row would be overwritten by this new insert as this column alone forms the primary key of the whole row.

The drawbacks of this solution is that you have to execute two queries for inserting instead of one and the usage of secondary indexes could make your queries slower. To improve the performance of the secondary index try to choose a column that doesn't have a very high cardinality (too many distinct values), so you have to choose between key_part_one and key_part_two which one would be the new primary key and which one to be the column used to create the secondary index.